# GitLab For Loop to Run Stages for Each of a Thing

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

With Jenkins Declarative Pipelines you can loop over a map to run stages for each element:

https://newbedev.com/for-loop-in-jenkins-pipeline-code-example

Is there a way to do this with GitLab CI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matrix, is the same logic.

[Here the doc about it.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel-matrix-jobs)

Comment: What is STACK referring to in the documentation?

Comment: Here's a good doc: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/06/21/how-to-become-more-productive-with-gitlab-ci/

Answer (score 3):

i know this got already answered, but i still will add some details etc. generally speaking answers, with just links are not good answers, as they might point to no where in the future.

As correctly stated by @Joao Vitorino there is the feature called `matrix builds`, which can be easily achieved via

```
jobs:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ENVIRONMENT: 
        - 'test'
        - 'foo'
  script: echo $ENVIRONMENT
```

This will generate two jobs one for `test` and one for `foo` and print out the respectively option. for further details see: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel-matrix-jobs You can also do multiple variables and connections like:

```yaml
  # copied from the official gitlab docs
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - PROVIDER: aws
        STACK:
          - monitoring
          - app1
          - app2
      - PROVIDER: ovh
        STACK: [monitoring, backup, app]
      - PROVIDER: [gcp, vultr]
        STACK: [data, processing]
```

Which most likely will solve all your cases. Additionally to that, `parallel:matrix` also works with `trigger`. This means you can create a whole pipeline which will be triggered with your properties as a [child pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#trigger-syntax-for-child-pipeline) like:

```
jobs:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ENVIRONMENT: 
        - 'test'
        - 'foo'
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: path/to/child-pipeline.yml
    strategy: depend
```

which will generate two child pipelines, in which you can add way more steps and logic, in an easier way than with normal `matrix:parallel`-builds